# How to make a portable version of Opera the default browser?

Tags: browser, opera, portable

I'd like to set Opera portable as the default browser. How can I do that? Thank you.

Comment: What platform you are using ? And what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Isn't the whole point of "_portable apps_" that they don't alter the wider system in any way or require elevated privileges?... which probably includes becoming the "_default browser_". (not saying this can't be done, just a bit perplexed)

Comment: your Opera portable did not run on my dos 6.0 at all :D may be you use different OS?

Answer (score 1):

**The following method worked for me to set OperaPortable as default browser to open external http and https links.**

I checked it using **Windows 7 x64 Pro SP1** and latest official **OperaPortable** version 58.0.3135.47 downloaded from Opera.com.

1) Create text file and paste text:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\OperaHTML]
@="Opera HTML"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\OperaHTML\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\port\\OperaPortable\\launcher.exe,0"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\OperaHTML\shell]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\OperaHTML\shell\open]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\OperaHTML\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\port\\OperaPortable\\launcher.exe\" -- \"%1\""


[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\https\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\port\\OperaPortable\\launcher.exe,0"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\http\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\port\\OperaPortable\\launcher.exe,0"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\https\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\port\\OperaPortable\\launcher.exe\" -- \"%1\""


[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\http\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\port\\OperaPortable\\launcher.exe\" -- \"%1\""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\https\UserChoice]
"Progid"="OperaHTML"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice]
"Progid"="OperaHTML"
```

2) Change the path to launcher.exe (in my example it's C:\port\OperaPortable\launcher.exe)
Don't delete double slashes.

3) save file with **.reg** extension, run and confirm it. Association should work after that (no need reboot).

---

If you need ftp-links also - add at the end of reg file at step 2.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ftp\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\port\\OperaPortable\\launcher.exe,0"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ftp\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\port\\OperaPortable\\launcher.exe\" -- \"%1\""
```

---

For html-**files** association just use as usual Shift + mouse Right click > Open with > and find your PortableBrowser in explorer.

Answer (score 0):

On the official Opera forum there is a [similar question](https://forums.opera.com/topic/18753/to-make-portable-version-as-default-browser/2) asked by user [bonami](https://forums.opera.com/user/bonami) that is more of a suggestion. Later he added a workaround for it for `Windows` platform. The method he describes as a workaround is basically :

#### [Registering an Application for Use with Default Programs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144154(v=vs.85).aspx)

- Copy contents of this **[`.reg`](https://ghostbin.com/paste/yqgdn)** script to a file.
- Save it as a `.reg` file.
- Execute it.
- Go to Default Program Settings & you should see your program there.

Being a Linux user, I am unable to try this, so you should give it a try and see whether if it works or not.

Feel free to add-in more details.